# how to get rid of draft and blank page in tex

Tags: backgrounds, draft

Wrote the following code (keeping it small to highlight the problem) using book class. Facing two issues with this code (same issue seen with both 'texstudio' & 'led' on windows10) :

1. "Draft" is getting printed on each page. How can i remove it ?
2. In between the two pages shown below, i am seeing a blank page with "draft" written on it. How to get rid of the blank page ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{background}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage} 
     \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bf book title}\\[5mm]
        {\Large\bf By author-name}
     \end{center}   
  \end{titlepage}   

\mainmatter 
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=0.1,  %% adjust
    contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{a.jpg}}
}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \begin{LARGE}
    \item line-1    
    \item line-2
  \end{LARGE}   
  \end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the word `draft` remove the `background` package. Also don't use `\bf`, this is obsolete

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{background}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage} 
     \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bfseries book title}\\[5mm]
        {\Large\bfseries By author-name}
     \end{center}   
  \end{titlepage}   

\mainmatter 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \LARGE
  \item line-1    
  \item line-2 
  \end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

---

To keep the background package around:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage} 
     \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bfseries book title}\\[5mm]
        {\Large\bfseries By author-name}
     \end{center}   
  \end{titlepage}   
\mainmatter 
\backgroundsetup{%
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=0.1,  %% adjust
    contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}
}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \LARGE
    \item line-1    
    \item line-2
  \end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

---

Different approach with the `eso-pic` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage} 
     \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bfseries book title}\\[5mm]
        {\Large\bfseries By author-name}
     \end{center}   
  \end{titlepage}   
\mainmatter 
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \LARGE
    \item line-1    
    \item line-2
  \end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

Or using tiks:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
  \begin{titlepage} 
     \begin{center}
        {\Huge\bfseries book title}\\[5mm]
        {\Large\bfseries By author-name}
     \end{center}   
  \end{titlepage}   
\mainmatter 

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\pgfsetfillopacity{0.1}
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}};
\pgfsetfillopacity{1}
\end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \LARGE
    \item line-1    
    \item line-2
  \end{enumerate}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry i forgot to include the code where i am using 'background' pkg to include a background image on each page. Added the code above now. If background pkg is the issue, is there any alternate way to include a background image on each page ?

Comment: @mezda If you need to keep the background package, you can change the default text, see my edited answer.

Comment: @mezda also added an alternative package

Comment: Thanks a ton. That helped solve the first problem. Now 'draft' is no longer coming. But still the blank page is coming. Do you have any idea on how to get rid of that ?

Comment: @mezda The blank page is supposed to be there because you use a documentclass which is two-sided by default. If you don't like, use `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}` or `article` class

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick replies. It helped solve both the issues.